# Does "She had a brother" mean that her brother is dead?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, past-simple, ambiguity

My Friend has sent me this riddle to solve:

> "If you solve this, then you are a genius. Mr.Smith has 4
>   daughters‍♀‍♀‍♀‍♀ and each daughter had a brother.  How many
>   children does Mr. Smith have now?"

He said the answer is not 5, but 4 only as in the riddle it is mentioned as each daughter **had** a brother. So their only brother is dead.

Is he right?

Comment: There was never one brother. There were four brothers since each daughter had one. Presumably they are now dead.

Comment: @Lambie If there were four brothers, then each daughter wouldn't have had one. Each daughter would have had four.

Comment: Four daughters, each had a brother=four brothers. But they are all dead: each daughter HAD a brother. The answer is four. But the riddle is weird to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Using the past tense certainly *implies* that brother has died, but this is not universally true.  For example, in narrative it's common to backshift all verbs to the past tense.

> Not long ago there was a man with four daughters, and each of the daughters **had** a small dog.  One day the daughters were out playing with their dogs when suddenly ...

The present vitality of the dogs is ambiguous, and in fact unimportant to the story.  Because backshifting is a common narrative device, with your joke you should not assume the brother is dead.  Another example:

> When I was growing up I **had** a brother who used to get into all kinds of trouble.

From this, you could not definitively say that my brother is now dead.  Again, in the context of the story it doesn't matter, and you'd have to explicitly ask if you wanted to know.

Anyway, the main point of the joke is to recognize each of the daughters would have the *same* male sibling, and not *four separate* male siblings -- but, with the given information, it's impossible to say whether this brother is alive or dead.  You'd have to ask.

---

Related note:  As if that wasn't confusing enough, it's also common to use the present tense to talk about historic figures now deceased, especially when referring to the current effects of their past work:

> Even though he died when he was only 52 years old, William Shakespeare **is** still considered the most influential writer in all of English literature.

Comment: The riddle begins: ".... Mr.Smith **has** 4 daughters.... each daughter **had** a brother.... How many children **does** Mr Smith have **now**?.....In your answer, the story begins in the past ".... there **was** a man with....each daughter **had** a small dog...." and continues in the past. It's a trick question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Honestly, the use of have/had doesn't mean anything.  Please see my edited answer.

Comment: We're trying to guess what the author of the riddle intended? Several answers seem equally plausible to me. Maybe Rahul Yadav, the author of the question, should ask the author of the riddle whether he intend the change from "has" to "had" to be meaningful. Reread the question header. Does an expression would mean something? What does that would mean, oh experts?

Comment: @Chaim If the author of the joke was trying to ask a trick question using "had" to imply the brother is dead ... well, I don't think it works very well, given the ambiguity of "had" with regard to someone being currently alive.  I'll edit my answer to reflect your concern, but see my examples for other interpretations.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant to suggest that this sort of subtlety and close reading just seems to be ruled-out here. We cannot know the meaning of the riddle. I thought the point was that in a family with three girls and one boy, each girl has a brother, and we need not posit a different boy for each girl (as Lambie does in a comment to the original question). But who knows? Nobody but the author of the riddle.

Comment: @Chaim It's like the ["As I was going to St. Ives"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_I_was_going_to_St_Ives) nursery rhyme, with several possible answers depending on how you interpret *"I **met**"*.

Comment: It's a trick question, the whole idea  is to fool us into assuming the obvious.  If the 4 daughters are alive then we naturally assume the same is true for their brother.  Our brains, our life's experiences are at fault here, not our command of the English language. Just like Lambie (maybe she's kidding) who literally interprets that each sister has a male sibling. But if that were the case, what would we say if there were a total of five brothers? That each sister had five brothers? No. Each sister **has** an *only* brother i.e all the sisters have the same brother.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I don't know what the obvious assumption would be here. I suppose that the most common answer, the one you'd get the most if kids posed this to riddle orally to their unsuspecting parents, is 8. If the parents were subtle enough to consider the tense shift (from "has" to "had") and the word "now" tagged oddly to the end, they might conclude with Rahul's friend, that the girls have survived their brothers (or brother), and only the four girls remain.

Comment: Personally I think the riddle would be improved by changing "had" to "has," eliminating the word "now," and considering the correct answer to be "five." The idea that one brother would suffice (to allow each girl to have one brother) is an amusing realization. The idea that children have died is not. And for the joke to depend on this sort of reasoning (that the past tense implies that someone has died) just points out the sort of ambiguity that is everywhere in normal language and not funny anymore. (I'm just sayin'.)

Comment: @Chaim this is inspired by a famous riddle that went viral on the net. There's one video where a teenager just can't get the solution, it teeters towards humiliation when her parents keep repeating the same riddle over and over again. The "classic" version contains the expression "each have" and asks how many members are in the family https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFrms2iEX4k

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I'll have a look when I'm out of class. But the truth is, from the point of view of English, there's no need to say "each sister" has (or had), about sisters who share one brother. A spoil-sport editor who did not know this was a riddle might suggest that if the sisters have only one brother in common, the statement should be "and they have one brother." So the person who responds that there are eight children has really understood English as she is spoke better than the person who says that there are four children.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Well I just learned something: some English people are absolutely adorable girls who call their relatives "bruver" and "mum," and are not any quicker than my students, but a lot more persistent. But even without all that, I would be firmly by her side in the argument that the word "each" is rendered meaningless by the answer in the video. The girl kept emphasizing that "each has a brother, so there are four." If I tell four people that I will pay them $1 each, have I committed to paying them a total of $1?

Comment: @Chaim look at it this way: There are four sisters and they each have a mother and a father. How many parents do the four sisters have? Sister No.1 has a mum and dad, so does sister no.2, and so on and so forth. But it's the same mother and father for all four sisters.

Comment: @Mari-Lou It strains imagination to explain four sisters and their parents as twelve people. Are they each other's sisters, or sisters to unnamed additional people, or what? Because of our strong sense of the ways of the world, we more easily overlook the still-inappropriate "each." I think I understand the analysis that leads the British parents to tell their daughter that the family in the riddle were seven people; but it's a forced way of reading the question and not the natural implications of the words of the question.

Answer (score 0):

honestly whatever happen to the brother, Mr Smith (father) has 5 children.

Question is how many children isnt it ? not asking how many living children, in that case whatever happen, they were 5 children.

Comment: No, if one child had died we wouldn't still say that the father 'has' that child. We would say that he 'had' the child, but the child is dead now. He used to have 5 but now he has four. If Mr. Smith were dead we'd say he had five children. He no longer has them because he's dead. Very confusing, I know.